# Having trouble with the script that loads a new scene in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I am learning to make a game and I have some compilation errors, but in my opinion the script looks fine. Basically what am I trying to do is when the character collides with a specific object the player should move to the next level/scene.

[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uGWI.png)

[the errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQPiL.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `;` in line 24 and it will work again.

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)